# How to set date in react native push notification?

Tags: react-native, android-notifications, react-native-push-notification

I am using react native push notification.

But when i am trying to push local schedule, notification not show as time expected. It always showed when i reload the app (same behaviour like *PushNotification.localNotification*

how to set date for parameter inside *PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule* ? i am confuse to set value there. I already using timestamp but looks like the value is different.

1578909865373 => using date.now

1578907260 => i convert from string date to timestamp

my code :

```
   function toTimestamp(strDate){
    var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
    return datum/1000;
   }

   const dated= toTimestamp('01/13/2020 16:21:00');

    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
        message: "testing notification", // (required)
        date:  date: new Date(dated)  // in 60 secs
        // date: new Date("2020/01/13")
      });
    }
```

please help how to insert or convert right value for date.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Turn out i dont have to divide by 1000
timestamp is milliseconds.

so right function is

```
function toTimestamp(strDate){
var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
return datum;
}
```